# Upexpaned update : How to use find and update the array of another schema in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two schema . One is like this.

```
var tripSchema = mongoose.Schema({

distance :{
    type: 'Number',
    required: true

},
source : {
     latitude: {
        type: 'Number',
        required: true
     },
    longitude: {
        type: 'Number',
        required: true  
    }
},
destination: {
     latitude: {
        type: 'Number',
        required: true
    },
    longitude: {
        type: 'Number',
        required: true  
    }
},
tripON:{
        type : 'Boolean',
        default: false
    }
}
```

and another schema like this

```
var userTrips = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref : 'users'

    },
 trips : [tripSchema]
});
```

Now by using some query I already created a document like this.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("561bf7c0a3724f066b834985"),
    "userId" : ObjectId("561bda2117a4b49362b14dfb"),
    "deviceId" : "58",
    "carId" : "abcd123",
    "trips" : [
        {
            "startTime" : ISODate("2015-05-20T15:28:55Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("561ea4df42d8b60947a79b4b"),
            "tripON" : true,
            "source" : {
                "latitude" : 13.07,
                "longitude" : 77.6181319
            }
        }]
```

Now to change the value of tripON to false I wrote this query and mind you I don't want to upsert but strictly update.

```
Trip.update({ userId: deviceUserCarMap.userId, deviceId: deviceId, carId: deviceUserCarMap.carId},
                        { $set: { 'trips.$.destination': { latitude: lat, longitude: lng }, 'trips.$.tripON': false} }, null,
                        function (err, trip) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log('Trip End Saved');
                                userCache.toggleTripFlag(userIndex);
                                console.log(trip);
                            }
                        });
```

and I get an error like.

```
[MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: trips.$.destination]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: trips.$.destination',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 16837,
  errmsg: 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: trips.$.destination' }
```

How can I solve it?
Edit : 
Even after giving this query : `db.trips.findOne({'trips.0._id' : ObjectId("561ea4df42d8b60947a79b4b") })` I get all the elements of tripSchema array in userTrips and not just one. Why?

Comment: A possible [solution](https://brodan.biz/blog/the-struggles-of-a-mongodb-newbie/). But I don't know how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the answer... Not the whole thing though. But here is the approach from the link given in comment.

> “The $ operator can update the first array element that matches
>   multiple query criteria specified with the$elemMatch() operator.”
>
> “When used with update operations, e.g. db.collection.update() and
>   db.collection.findAndModify(), the positional $ operator acts as a
>   placeholder for the first element that matches the query document.”
>
> “The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse
>   more than one array… because the replacement for the $ placeholder is
>   a single value”

So you will have to write a script in MongoDB. Now how to write that.

1. In your ~/data/db folder create a folder called scripts and in that create a myScript.js file.
2. In that write `db = connect("localhost:27017/metaiot")`;
3. Now go to your mongo shell and type `load(fullpath/data/db/scripts/myScript.js)`. In my case it looked like `load("/home/oroborus/data/db/scripts/myScript.js")` . If it successful load will return true. If you get an error it means your file path is wrong. Please give full path name. Even if mongo documentation says relative paths work don't listen to them. use absolute path. I discovered this through trial and error.
4. Now it is true write a script something like this. It is modification of the script given in the comments of question. Tailor made for my use.

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/metaiot");
    var numbers = db.trips.find({trips :{$elemMatch : {"tripON":false}}});
    numbers.forEach(function(setter)
        { for(var index in setter.trips){

            print(setter.trips[index]._id)
        }
    });
```

Now do whatever you like to do. It took me 3 hours to figure this out. But it was worth it.